¿Cómo desactivar login de MX LINUX XFCE basado en DEBIAN?
Necesito de su ayuda ya que no puedo entrar a mi computadora, tengo instalado MX LINUX XFCE de 64 bits.
Estuve instalando OpenJDK 21 en mi sistema, luego, al apagarlo, cuando lo encendi me apareció el login como se muestra en la imagen adjunta. Nunca me había pedido la contraseña, y me pareció rarísimo.

Ya intenté escribir correctamente mi contraseña y de ahí no pasa. Hice una indagación en Google al respecto, y sólo puedo entrar a la consola tecleando: Ctrl+Alt+F1, después en la consola escribo mi usuario y contraseña; una vez dentro, tecleo el comando: startx, y entonces así pude entrar, y solo con eso puedo usar mi computadora, pero cuando lo apago y vuelvo a encender, me aparece de nuevo el login sin poder entrar al sistema.

Espero me puedan apoyar a resolverlo. Gracias.

Acabo de tener un problema parecido. Espero que esto pueda ayudarte.
Tengo un viejo laptop con Linux Mint 20.2 Uma, XFCE y lightdm. Está máquina opera de firewall y está configurada con login automático a mi cuenta de usuario.
Hacia mucho que no la actualizaba y luego de la última actualización, dejo de logearse automáticamente en mi cuenta. Sin embargo, todavía podía entrar dando mi contraseña.
Solución
Editar el archivo /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf y asegurarse de configurar estas tres líneas así:
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=candidmoe
autologin-user-timeout=0

Obvio, en lugar de candidmoe pones la cuenta que te interesa.
Si quieres forzar a logearse con usuario/password, deja en blanco el campo autologin-user, así:
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=
autologin-user-timeout=0

Luego rebootea.

en ciertas configuraciones verificar también si existe el grupo autologin y el user es parte del grupo. y como siempre para evitar q se pierda la config en actualizaciones se puede crear un archivo en conf.d para cada user o para los user locales

@aloMalbarez. En Linux Mint al menos no aparece.

cla, depende la config y el upgrade path  a veces el prefer maintainer config te vuela personalizaciones ( ahi buscar la carpeta conf.d del service y meter todo lo relevante q quedo en el .old ) y a veces hay un post install script que limpia grupos o users de grupos
